# Reference to chrome when I try to open a URL with a Firefox webdriver using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

This code opens Firefox and gets the URL `chrome://browser/content/www.google.com`.

What is the cause of this error?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("www.google.com")
```

I'm using:

- Selenium version 3.0.1
- Python version 3.5.2
- Firefox versions 50 and 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your `.get` request with `http://` or `https://` in front of `www.google.com`